# How to mock module which depends implicitly per test in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, integration-testing

I have an **integration test** where I make actual DB calls to the MongoDB database. But in order to test whether the transaction is expired or not, I need to **mock the DB for that particular test**. There are many reasons for me to make the actual DB call, I'm mentioning the state just for the sake of this example.

Jest has `jest.doMock` function but that is helpful only when I wanted to import the function within the test but in my case, It's the DB function which I wanted to mock for that particular test when is getting called inside the express middleware.

There is another option to mock the entire `../db` module but that will complicate the tests a lot in my actual project. It would be very easy for me if I can mock the DB call for a specific test and for rest all the tests it should make the real DB calls.

Is there a way to do it in Jest?

```
// a.ts
import express from "express"
import db from "../db";

const app = express()

app.get("/api/deduct-balance/:txn_id", (req, res) => {
  const txn = await db.findById(txn_id)
  
  // return error message if txn expired
  if (txn.exipre_at <= new Date()) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "txn expired" });
  }

  // otherwise update the txn state
  txn.state = "DEDUCTED";
  await txn.save()

  return res.status(200).json();
});
```

```
// a.test.ts
import db from "../db";

describe("mixed tests", () => {
  test("should make REAL db calls", async () => {
    await axios.get("/api/deduct-balance/123")
    const txn = await db.findById("123");
    expect(txn.state).toBe("DEDUCTED");
  });

  test("should use MOCKED value", async () => {
    // need a way to mock the DB call so that I can return an expired transaction
    // when I hit the API

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/deduct-balance/123")
    
    expect(data).toBe({
      error: {
        message: "txn expired"
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: These kind of tests are better not done as integration tests. If you want to test the behavior of the request handler you should mock all dependencies to create a predictable and repeatable test. Module `db` should be a complete mock and `findById` should return a mock transaction and so on...

Comment: @Bart then which type of tests should I do as integration tests? Interested to know what are your thoughts on it.

Comment: I left an answer about the general gist. I have to go unfortunately but I can expand my answer at some later stage to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Integration tests are overkill for this scenario. Simple unit tests would suffice. They are fast to execute, test exactly one thing and you should have lots of them.

Because you're defining the handler as an anonymous function it's hard to unit test by default. So the first action is to make it easier to test by extracting it.

```
// deduct-balance-handlers.ts
export const deductBalanceByTransaction = async (req, res) => {
   const txn = await db.findById(txn_id)

   // return error message if txn expired
   if (txn.exipre_at <= new Date()) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "txn expired" });
   }

   // otherwise update the txn state
   txn.state = "DEDUCTED";
   await txn.save()

   return res.status(200).json();
}
```

It will also makes the app configuration more clean.

```
// a.ts
import express from "express"
import db from "../db";
import { deductBalanceByTransaction } from './deduct-balance-handlers';
const app = express()

app.get("/api/deduct-balance/:txn_id", deductBalanceByTransaction);
```

Now it's easy to reuse the handler in your test without relying on the web framework or database.

```
// a.test.ts
import db from "../db";
import { deductBalanceByTransaction } from './deduct-balance-handlers';

jest.mock('../db');

describe("deduct-balance", () => {
  test("Expired transaction should respond with 401 status", async () => {
    const response = mockResponse();
    deductBalanceByTransaction(request, response);
    expect(response.status).toBe(401);
  });
})
```

For simplicity's sake I left the part of creating a mock response and mocking the module out of the code. More can be learned about mocking here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Comment: I really appreciate the answer @Bart but I have purposefully kept the example code snippets small to make the explanation simple. On the real project, it's much more complicated than that and that's why I need an integration test. The approach that you have mentioned above I use that in many of my tests but my main challenge here is whether can I mock modules which depends implicitly in only a single test.

If you can tell me whether that's possible in Jest or not then it would be very helpful. :)

Comment: One thing I would consider first is thinking about the architecture of the code. Does it hinder testing? If it does you have an indication that there's something not right about the design of the code. In case of your example the handler has a lot of responsibilities like talking to the database and decide on edge-cases. Typically request handlers only do one thing handling the input (request) and output (response) of service layer objects. It shouldn't do anything else as it's a HTTP transport layer.
If the design is simple you'll have less dependencies and deal less with mocks.

Comment: The solution you want for your test isn't a good solution. Mocking out a module can work if you run tests in different suites/files but I wouldn't recommend it because it's confusing. You're very likely to  overcomplicate your tests because the code cannot be easily tested in it's current design.

Comment: Okay, assuming my code design is not good and I wanted to change it. Do you have certain open source libraries as an example preferably backend projects? Or someone else's which I can look for a certain approach.

Comment: It's not something you can learn from looking at other projects. You will miss the intent on why it's designed like it is. It's more about software engineering, and breaking things into sensible modules. Keep responsibilities and dependencies to a minimum and rethink your designs over and over.